# Create auto generated forms for each new table

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I use yii2 framework in my application and I have a table named objects in my SQL database

```
"objects" ( object_id , object_typeID , ... )
```

But we have some objects that have special fields and user should be able to add custom fields to objects form

My solution is create a new table named object-type-"index" for each new objects that have custom fields!

But how should I automatically create custom form for each object-type-"index" tables? Can I use gii module to generate automatic forms?

Comment: Any idea about my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom fields you should have two additional tables for all "objects":

```
[object_field_value]
object_id | field_id | value
    2     |    5     |  Yes
    2     |    6     |  Blue
    3     |    5     |  No

[object_field]
ID |    name      | [other attributes for field]
 5 |  Colorful?   |
 6 |  Base color  |
```

That way you can match object with it's all fields